# Is there any better way of using for loop?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am writing a code for a (128 bits)power of(4 bits) and a divider to find the remainder of (128 bits)power of(4 bits) and a variable of (4 bits). I used repetitive addition to find the first operation and repetitive subtraction to find a remainder. I used for loop to do the same. the upper bound of for loop is really high for (128 bits)power of(4 bits) and the simulation is giving an error. The simulation stops suddenly saying the process has been terminated. And a fatal error is found in module power(Xilinx 12.1 on windows xp).
This error pops up on xilinx 14.7 on windows 10:

> ERROR:Portability:3 - This Xilinx application has run out of memory or
>   has    encountered a memory conflict.  Current memory usage is 3085052
>   kb.  You can    try increasing your system's physical or virtual
>   memory.  If you are using a    Win32 system, you can increase your
>   application memory from 2GB to 3GB using    the /3G switch in your
>   boot.ini file. For more information on this, please    refer to Xilinx
>   Answer Record #14932. For technical support on this issue,    please
>   visit http://www.xilinx.com/support.

The simulator has terminated in an unexpected manner.  Please review the ISim log (isim.log) for details.
 Is there any efficient way to avoid this problem? please do help.
To find power:

```
entity power is
    Port ( mes : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (207 downto 0);
           d : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           outt : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2007 downto 0);
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC);
end power;

architecture Behavioral of power is
signal mes1:unsigned (207 downto 0);
signal d1:unsigned (11 downto 0);
signal mes3:unsigned (2007 downto 0);
begin
process(clk)
begin
if(clk'event and clk='1') then
mes1<=unsigned(mes);
d1<=unsigned(d);
end if;
end process;

process(clk,mes1)
variable varr:unsigned (2007 downto 0);
variable cnt,cnt1: unsigned (207 downto 0);
variable mes2: unsigned (2007 downto 0);
begin

cnt:=x"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001";
mes2:=x"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
mes2(207 downto 0):=mes1;
if(clk'event and clk='1') then
for i in 0 to 90 loop
     if(cnt<d1) then
      varr:=x"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
      cnt1:=x"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001";
           for j in 0 to 150000 loop
               if (cnt1<=mes1) then
                    varr:=varr+mes2;
                      cnt1:=cnt1+1;
                end if;
            end loop;
              mes2:=varr;
              cnt:=cnt+1;
      end if;
end loop;
mes3<=mes2;
end if;
end process;


process(clk)
begin
if(clk'event and clk='1') then
outt<=std_logic_vector(mes3);
end if;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

To find the remainder:

```
entity div22 is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2007 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           remi : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2007 downto 0);
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC);
end div22;

architecture Behavioral of div22 is

signal q:unsigned (11 downto 0);
signal a1,r:unsigned (2007 downto 0);
signal b1:unsigned (7 downto 0);
--signal i:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
begin

process(clk)
begin
if(clk'event and clk='1') then
a1<=unsigned(a);
b1<=unsigned(b);
end if;
end process;

process(clk,a1,b1)
variable remo1,remo2: unsigned(2007 downto 0);
begin
remo1:=a1;
if RISING_EDGE(clk) then
for i in 0 to 150000 loop
      remo2:=remo1;

     if(remo2>=b1) then
      remo1:=remo2-b1; 

      end if;
end loop;
r<=remo1;
end if;
end process;
process(clk,r)
begin
if RISING_EDGE(clk) then
remi<= std_logic_vector(r);
end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

To find the reminder the upper bound for for loop is really high. Is there any efficient way to solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: What error is it giving? What problem are you trying to solve? You'll find that your question gets closed if you're not more specific.

Comment: @EML The error is not specified. It just says some fatal error in power when i increase the upper bound of the loop

Comment: It's probably the massive arrays you are using.  Have you tried using a 64bit system with more ram?  Also , this code is not going to synthesise.  The iteration loop limit for synthesis is usually 10000, and even then,  the resource usage for this code will likely be bigger than any fpga, plus the max clock speed will be very slow.  I recommend designing the circuit on paper before writing the code.  Translating c to vhdl for synthesis will always give poor results.

Comment: @Tricky Im using 64 bit system with 8gb ram.  Is there any method for looping other than for loop.?

Comment: @Tricky in my code unrolling the loop eats up lot of resources. So i wanted an efficient way of looping.

Comment: I think us experienced HDL designers are wondering what you are trying to do. Why are you using HDL writing code which never, ever will fit in an FPGA or even ASIC.  This makes me think you have an X-Y problem. So what is the problem/algorithm you are trying to solve. Because I suspect this is not the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @Oldfart Im implementing rsa encryption alogorithm for a message of size 128 bit. I know now that using for loop is impossible task in this case. So I wanted to know a more efficient way than for loop.

Comment: OK, now we are getting somewhere. Your question falls in the "How do I
implement X" category. Unfortunately in this case ***there is no quick and
simple answer***. Basically you have to complete re-write
the code splitting it into steps which are solved in consecutive cycles, balancing
parallel and sequential operations which make optimal use of the
avialable clock frequency. It would take a steep learning curve of many months to teach you how to write efficient HDL for that. I suggest start looking at HDL code on the www which does likewise algorithms.

Comment: @Oldfart thank you sir. I really appreciate your help. Im a beginner in vhdl. I just started a month ago. Im still learning things. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The best way in your context is do no use loops.

Generally to get best performance and acceptable implementation area size you should use state implementation (fsm). You should balance between frequency (critical path) and number of cycles needed to finish work. This is my base implementation (in Verilog) of 'The rest of the total division -  remainder' operation from My master thesis. In my case the problem is that the adder was to big. So in My final version adding implementation is parallel - I used few smaller adder to get better frequency. This code is part of RSA implementation of My master thesis.

```verilog
module div(a,n,clk,reset,R, ready); // a,b,n mniejszy rozmiar
// a mod n = R
parameter size=1024; // data length

parameter
  A0 = 2'b00, // Reset.
  A1 = 2'b01, // Find  _n > _R.  
  A2 = 2'b10, // Calc.
  A3 = 2'b11; // Ready - calc done.

input [size-1:0] a,n;

input clk,reset;
output ready;
output [size-1:0] R;

reg signed [size:0] _R;
reg [size:0] _n;
reg [size-1:0] tmp_r;
reg ready; // operation is done.
reg [11:0]i;

(*safe_implementation = "yes"*)// directive for XST
(* signal_encoding = "user" *) // directive for XST

(* fsm_encoding = "user" *)    // directive for XST
reg [1:0] cs;

initial
  begin
     _R = 0;
     _n = 0;
     i = 0;
     ready = 0;
      tmp_r = 0;
      cs = A0;
  end



always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    if (reset)
       begin
          _R = a;
          _n = n;
          i = 0;
          tmp_r= a;
          ready = 0;
          cs = A0;
        end
     else
    begin
       case(cs)
          A0:
            begin
               cs = A1; 
             end
          A1:
            begin
            _n = _n << 1;
               i = i + 1;
               if ( _n > _R )
                 begin
                    _n = _n >> 1;
                _R = _R - _n;                 
                    cs = A2;
                  end
               else
                 begin
                    cs = A1;
                  end
             end
          A2:
            begin
               if (i==0)
                  begin
                    cs = A3;
                  end
                else
                  begin
                    _n = _n >> 1;
                  if (_R[size]==1'b0)
                    begin
                       tmp_r = _R;  // Save last positiv number. 
                        _R = _R - _n;
                     end
                  else
                    begin
                       _R = _R + _n;
                     end
                  i = i -1;
                  cs = A2;
               end    
             end
          A3:
            begin
               ready = 1'b1;
               cs = A3;
             end
          default:;  
        endcase
    end
  end

assign R=tmp_r;  
endmodule
```

[image: div fsm]

You can find in My master thesis more tricks to get better performance and area optimization applicable to your context  ( the problem is that it is in Polish): 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332752272_Realizacja_wybranych_algorytmow_kryptograficznych_w_strukturach_FPGA_Smolinski_Lukasz

Sorry for my English.